# How to scroll paging grid in Extjs 5.1.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using Extjs 5.1.1 How to scroll paging grid I should? I cannot find some examples.who has some examples?I am new.Please help me!

Comment: In sencha extjs docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging

Comment: thank you,but i do not want to use paging toolbar.I want to paging by scrolling.

Comment: You need to use bufferedstore in that case

Comment: I tried to use bufferedstore.But i found rowediting is not working.This say that bufferedstore is readonly.[link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?293432-Issue-with-Ext.data.BufferedStore-Ext-JS-5)

Comment: If its not possible by default then you have 2 possibilties: Override buferredstore and add this functionality or just make pagingtoolbar. First option could be difficult to implement but not impossible.

Comment: Thank you. buferredstore now it is working.It is my wrong config.Now I can use scroll paging and rowediting.

Comment: Now getModifiedRecords is not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working ? Show error and please update your code with current state. Will be much easier to understand.

Comment: var store = this.getLegGrid().getStore();
        var modifiedRecords = store.getModifiedRecords();
        for(var i = 0;i<modifiedRecords.length;i++){
            modifiedRecords[i].reject();}

Comment: Add your code to your question. And post your error.

Comment: the modifiedRecords.length always is zero.But the grid had marked the cell dirty.